# What is the probability of two people in a family of 10 dying of opioid pain killers?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Given the odds of dying of opioid pain-killers is 1 in 109

then
p = 1/110
do we use

```
dbinom(2,10,(1/110))-dbinom(3,10,(1/110))
```

Comment: I really doubt that occurrence of death due to opiod pain killers is independent across members of the same family.

Comment: The argument makes no sense. What are your assumptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea behind your calculations would, I think, be correct IF the two events were independent. That is almost certainly not true in this case. People are more likely to use opiates if their siblings do, for all sorts of reasons. E.g. the use of opiates is related to geography, social and economic status, age and other things.

Even if they were independent, however, I think you have misused the R functions. I think you want pbinom rather than dbinom.

Comment: And in addition to non-independence is use of opiods, propensity of dying given use may also not be independent due to genetic as well as geographic and other factors.